# How to reverse inbuilt icon

Tags: ios, swift

I have this icon pointing towards right, how do I change it so as to point to the left

```
VC.labelSelected = self.details[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] + "✏️"
```

Comment: what is `labelSelected`, how it is defined? I missed that.

Comment: var labelSelected = String()

Comment: What about using  or ? 

Comment: I was thinking same thing but yellow color was more suited for my background; guess I have to go with those

Comment: @kennytm where did you get that second icon

Answer (score 0):

Take only `self.details[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]` to the next screen.

Assign icon to the `labelIcon`, Flip it, hide it and than assign its text to the `labelSelected`.

```
labelIcon.text = "✏️"
labelIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
labelIcon.hidden = true

labelSelected.text = self.details[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] + labelIcon.text
```

Comment: It will reverse the whole string OP only want to reverse "✏️"

Comment: Edited the answer. The two labels need to be horizontally together.

Comment: Ya, it won't work, `labelSelected ` made me thought that it is label instead of string.

Comment: where will you use `labelSelected`?

Comment: I use it in the next view controller to display text, so basically I want o give user an option to edit their text, so I am trying to add this icon next to the text that will be displayed.

Comment: It will complicate things to add additional label as I dont know the characters that will be in the labelSelected and there will be large gap between text and icon